# csv file operation: compare two csv files and return all matched line with header

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I am trying to compare columns of two CSV files and save all matched lines to a new CSV file with a header. Below are the example files

```
file1:
ID,type,gene,startpos,endpos,product    
C20775336,marker,gene1,1895,2166,ID=gene1;Name=maker-C20
C20775337,marker,gene2,895,1166,ID=mRNA1;Parent=gene1;N
C20775339,marker,gene3,1895,1962,Parent=mRNA1
C20775335,marker,gene4,2795,2962,ID=CDS1;Parent=mRNA1
C20775338,marker,gene5,895,1166,ID=mRNA1;Parent=gene1;N

file2:
Id,start,End
C2002,895,1166
C2003,1895,2166
C2004,2795,2962
```

here I am trying to compare columns 4th and 5th of file1 with columns 2nd and 3rd of file2 and save it to a new CSV file if matched.

using this command `awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{A[$2,$3]=$0;next} A[$4,$5]'  file2 file1` I am getting this output:

```
C20775336,marker,gene1,1895,2166,ID=gene1;Name=maker-C20
C20775337,marker,gene2,895,1166,ID=mRNA1;Parent=gene1;N
C20775335,marker,gene4,2795,2962,ID=CDS1;Parent=mRNA1
C20775338,marker,gene5,895,1166,ID=mRNA1;Parent=gene1;N
```

But I want the header of file1 as well which is achieved if the header name is identical in both files for example if `startpos` and `endpos` of file1 changed to `start` and `end` or vice-versa.

is there any way without having an identical header name, it can be done. So my expected output file will be like:

```
output:
ID,type,gene,startpos,Endpos,product    
C20775336,marker,gene1,1895,2166,ID=gene1;Name=maker-C20
C20775337,marker,gene2,895,1166,ID=mRNA1;Parent=gene1;N
C20775335,marker,gene4,2795,2962,ID=CDS1;Parent=mRNA1
C20775338,marker,gene5,895,1166,ID=mRNA1;Parent=gene1;N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use another condition `FNR == 1`:

```sh
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {A[$2,$3]=$0; next} FNR == 1 || ($4,$5) in A' f2 f1

ID,type,gene,startpos,endpos,product
C20775336,marker,gene1,1895,2166,ID=gene1;Name=maker-C20
C20775337,marker,gene2,895,1166,ID=mRNA1;Parent=gene1;N
C20775335,marker,gene4,2795,2962,ID=CDS1;Parent=mRNA1
C20775338,marker,gene5,895,1166,ID=mRNA1;Parent=gene1;N
```